# Tagging: "identify-this-game" versus "identify-this-program"

Tags: discussion, tags

So, [this](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/3228/looking-for-a-specific-basic-music-program-from-the-80s) software-identification question just came up.  We've got [identify-this-computer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-computer) for hardware, and [identify-this-game](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-game) for games, but nothing for identifying software in general.  Do we want a dedicated [identify-this-software](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-software) tag for non-game software, or should we re-name [identify-this-game](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-game) to be for all software?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting point.  My preference would be to leave [identify-this-game](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-game) alone as the seven questions using it are well defined and games constitute a major segment of retro - home - computers.  Also, [identify-this-computer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-computer) is for hardware.

A new tag for identification of non-game software would be appropriate.

I don't think we should go mad...
Creating [identify-this-compiler](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-compiler), [identify-this-spreadsheet](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-spreadsheet) *ad nauseam* would be over the top.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be more apropriate to have a general [identify-this](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this) tag to cover all of this? The demo vs. game vs software issue already shows how fuzzy it would be to find the right identify-this-* version. And taging the wrong will devaluate the tag usage. So a more general might be a better idea. Wouldn't it?

Comment: Possibly.  Then again, we have *identify-this-computer* to refer to hardware.  *Identify-this-software* is a catch-all that can be used for any form of software.

Comment: Well, @Chenmunka, yes. but why not a general identify-this while keeping indentify-this-computer as **one** special case? Tags don't have to be strictly ether or nor do they have to split a spectrum in eual parts or name all parts. They should help classifying in a human way.

Answer (score 0):

The question referred in the post would likely benefit from [identify-this-demo](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-demo); maybe the scope of [identify-this-game](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-game) can be widened just so.